# What are the rewards given to newbies in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I started playing League of Legends a while ago (one year ago or so...), this week, a friend of mine said to me that they are giving RP besides IP Boost for the newbies in the game.

- What are those rewards ?
- What are the requirements ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following forum thread (in date of the Feb-08-2012) states that :

> In keeping with this objective, we’re going to begin distributing some rewards to our new players to help them on their way to level 30. Once a new summoner reaches level 3 they will receive 400 Riot Points as a reward for their participation and perseverance up to that point.
>   *See [[1](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1799843)]*

Other accounts have received these 400 RP in december [[2](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/450-riot-points-awarded-nice-summoners)].

Comment: And about the IP boost?

Comment: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=18184268#18184268 maybe?? Did not find anything else.

Comment: From your link: "New accounts that are under Summoner Level 10 get a boost to help them get started--it makes it a tad easier to pick up your first champion as well. However, after Summoner Level 10, your earnings go back to normal rates when you win or lose matches."